# How to configure two default routes on Linux?

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I'm configuring a routing server with Linux.

1. An Ethernet link (eth0) to internet (fast, but can't access some sites);
2. An OpenVPN link (tun0) to provide internet access to local users;
3. An OpenVPN link (tun1) to a proxy server which is the second internet link (slow, free).

My target is like this: for common internet access, routing them through eth0; for the sites can't be linked with eth0, routing them through tun1.

The initial experiments are successful. I set the routing table manually for a few testing sites and it works as expected. But there are thousands of them and with time going it changes. Thus I must seek another way.

I tried to config quagga (with zebra and ospfd enabled) and wish it automatically going through tun1 while users fail to access a site through link 1(eth0). Actually I configured both tun1 and eth0 as default routes but I don't get what I wish.

The problem blocked me for a few days. I'm not familiar with ospf so I don't know if it possible with ospfd.

I need your suggestions! Please correct me if there is a better way.

Comment: It's not possible to use more than one _default_ route, because by definition the _default_ route is the one to use if no other entry in the routing table matches. (If you have multiple default routes, the one with the lowest metric will be used.)

Comment: More than one default route is possible under some configurations including line-detection based fail-over and round-robin based load balancing. They are not good for my case.

Comment: This needs a program that does stateful connection tracking, that is looking at outbound traffic and corresponding inbound traffic for the respective connections, and then updates routing table according to rules. I am not aware of any such software, and I'm not sure if such a software can be implemented in such a way that it would work reasonably. Your only option might be manual addition of routes.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes, somehow I need a smart router which remembers recently successful routes. It should be a common requirement for routers and not very difficult to implement IMO. As routers being used everywhere for decades, I thought it should be easy to find such a software on Linux but I failed by now. Are there really specific technical issues preventing us from such a software?

Answer (score -1):

I understand the problem here is that you need to set routing rules on OpenVPN client machines? Have you tried route pushing in OpenVPN server config?

```
push "route IP MASK vpn_gateway";
```

(replace *IP* and *MASK* accordingly to match your routing targets).

Using *ccd* option you can even push different rules on per-client basis. Consult `man openvpn` for details. Remember to include *pull* or *client* directive in client configs.

Comment: Not exactly. I can set routing limited rules. Actually several thousand of such rules need to be set without considering efficiency issues. Another way is to allow a daemon adding such routes when a default route failed for IP address requested. There are multiple failure situations: no route to destination; ping timeout; http/https failure; other failure. Considering efficiency, it should be like a routing cache which updates according to recent internet access results.